# Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed

Tags: docker, .net-core

I created a basic Rest API using ASP.NET Core 5 i want to make run with docker. The application works fine on IIS Express.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

[image]

I also want to create a docker container in order to launch the application.

In the project folder i created a Docker folder with several files.
**Here is my App.dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

ARG WEBAPP_VERSION=0.0.1
LABEL maintainer=anymail@email_server.com \
    Name=webapp \
    Version=${WEBAPP_VERSION}
ARG URL_PORT
WORKDIR /app
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:${URL_PORT}
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "WebApplication.dll" ]
```

I also have a Build.docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
## Can be Debug or Release.
ARG BUILD_CONFIG=Debug
ARG BUILDER_VERSION=0.0.1
LABEL maintainer=some_email@email_server.com \
    Name=webapp-build-${BUILD_CONFIG} \
    Version=${BUILDER_VERSION}
## Will be the path mapped to the external volume.
ARG BUILD_LOCATION=/app/out
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . /app
RUN dotnet publish --output ${BUILD_LOCATION} --configuration ${BUILD_CONFIG}
```

Finally I have a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp.test
    image: webapp:${WEBAPP_VERSION}
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./Docker/App.dockerfile
      args:
        WEBAPP_VERSION: ${WEBAPP_VERSION}
        URL_PORT: ${URL_PORT}
    ports:
      - "5000:${URL_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - appbuild:/app
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_SERVER_NAME: ${MYSQL_SERVER_NAME}
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    depends_on:
      - builder
  
  builder:
    container_name: builder
    image: webapp:${BUILDER_VERSION}.${BUILD_CONFIG}
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./Docker/Build.dockerfile
      args:
        BUILDER_VERSION: ${BUILDER_VERSION}
        BUILD_CONFIG: ${BUILD_CONFIG}
        BUILD_LOCATION: ${BUILD_LOCATION}
    volumes:
      - appbuild:${BUILD_LOCATION}
   
  mysql:
    container_name: ${MYSQL_SERVER_NAME}
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbvol:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    env_file:
      - secrets.env

volumes:
  appbuild:
  dbvol:
```

Finally, I launch the following command line :

```
docker build -f Docker/App.dockerfile -t webapp:Debug --build-arg URL_PORT=7909 .
```

[image]

the process is rather quick.
I also launch this command line :

```
docker run --name webapp.test -p 5000:7909 -it webapp:Debug
```

I unfortunatelly obtain an error message.

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'WebApplication.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: There is no `build` or `publish` step in your `dockerfile`. What is the Build.docker?

Comment: `App.Dockerfile` doesn't build anything, try the build with `Build.Dockerfile`.

Comment: build too ... I have the same error message
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed. and The application 'restore' does not exist.

Comment: In my case, I had a typo in ENTRYPOINT's dll name.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your build Dockerfile uses the ASP.NET Core runtime container image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
```

This container doesn't have an SDK, just the runtime. When you build it, it fails:

```
RUN dotnet restore
```

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed. and The application 'restore' does not exist
```

Because the `dotnet restore` command is an SDK command. It's not available if you are just using the runtime.

You should use the SDK container for your build Dockerfile (not your runtime Dockerfile, that's fine):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
```

Comment: I thought i thanked you... 2 years later i thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 20):

If you already installed the SDK and you have x64 machine;

Delete the following item from `System Variables` > `Path`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me. The C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet path came before C:\Program Files\dotnet so it was using the wrong dotnet.exe. After deleting the x86 path everything works normally now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried to re-install .net 6 SDK, tried repairing visual studio, nothing helped but this.

Comment: Thanks, I just deleted this directory and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In my case dot net SDKs were installed in different locations. A simple
`where.exe dotnet` on powershell returned the following
[image]

There were 2 entries in system environment variables i.e. The one with x86 was above so it was taking precedence, so I swapped both of them and hurray it started working.
Special thanks to
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnet-could-not-execute-because-the-application-was-not-found-or-a-compatible-net-sdk-is-not-installed

Comment: That where.exe utility is very helpful. I'm was glad to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same message while trying to configure Docker Container Debugging in VS Code for .NET 6. Couple of issues:

1. In tasks.json of VS Code the default `"target": "base"` was not working for me, because I used stage `build` in Dockerfile. So I commented it out... But [Docker extension needs it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core#_add-an-environment-variable-to-the-image) to inject the Debugging metadata.
   Changing to `"target": "build"` fixed the error.
2. I skipped the EXPOSE and ENV part because it worked via docker compose or while manually forwarding ports in cmd. Should be at the beginning of base/build stage:

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine as build
   WORKDIR /source
   EXPOSE 80                         #was missing
   ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80   #was missing
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when i changed
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0` 
to:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0`

Answer (score 0):

In my case volume mounting is created this kind of problem.

```
volumes:
  - ./docker/caadminservice/certificate:/**CAAdminService**
```

**CAAdminService** is the root folder in container. We should not mount that directly with host machine. It created me this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

Try installing .Net extension through Vs code

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Alper Ebicoglu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69615668/47775), I found just deleting the rogue `dotnet` dir fixed the problem:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`